# How to exclude Fragment from Jacoco code coverage

Tags: android, code-coverage, jacoco

I have used below code to exclude fragment but I unable to exlcude fragment from jacoco code coverage kindly help me on this.

```
task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport) {

def coverageSourceDirs = [
        'src/main/java'
]

group = "Reporting"
description = "Generates Jacoco coverage reports"
reports {
    xml {
        enabled = true
        destination "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/jacoco.xml"
    }
    csv.enabled false
    html {
        enabled true
        destination "${buildDir}/jacocoHtml"
    }
}

classDirectories = fileTree(
        dir: 'build/intermediates/classes/debug',
        excludes: ['**/R.class',
                   '**/R$*.class',
                   '**/BuildConfig.*',
                   '**/Manifest*.*',
                   '**/*Fragment*.*'
        ]
)

sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
additionalSourceDirs = files(coverageSourceDirs)
executionData = files('build/outputs/code - coverage/connected/flavors/smartcompanion/coverage.ec')
}
```

We used command below :-

```
gradlew connectedCheck
gradlew connectedAndroidTest
gradlew connectedDubugAndroidTest
```

Everytime in coverage report we able to see fragment.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to exclude files, you can filter them out:

```
classDirectories = fileTree(
    dir: 'build/intermediates/classes/debug',
    excludes: ['**/R.class',
               '**/R$*.class',
               '**/BuildConfig.*',
               '**/Manifest*.*',
               '**/*Fragment*.*'
    ]
).filter ({file -> !file.name.contains('Fragment')})
```

For some reason I was also unable to exclude fragments. I couldn't find out what went wrong. Filtering them out by name worked though. So it kinda feels like a workaround, but at least I could move on and get my work done.

I also noticed that on Android, the different versions of Gradle and the jacoco plugin are not always very compatible. So it might help to experiment with downgrading (or upgrading) too.

Comment: How are you able to set a value to the read-only `classDirectories` variable?

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't worked on any Jacoco-related stuff in the last two years and don't have access to that project anymore. So I can't give you a good answer. All I remember is that it worked for what I was doing  at the time :-)

Comment: No problem.  This is one of those things we do once and then forget.  For those wondering: the latest version of jacoco (0.8.8) `classDirectories.setFrom()` does allow changes.